# jquery place a tooltip on top-right corner of its container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

An this is what i got so far.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.progress-bar').tooltip({ placement: 'right' });
        $('.carousel.slide').carousel({ interval: false });
        $('.progress-bar').tooltip('show', placement('top'));
    });
```

This is the little javascript code i got so far. I tried using top and left both for placement (i imagined they won't work, but a man can dream, eh?).

This is my html for the said progress bars.

```
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 55%" data-title="55%">
                                    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h6>Graphic Design</h6>
                            <div class="progress" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="70%">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 70%">
                                    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h6>WordPress Development</h6>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%">
                                    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h6>HTML & CSS</h6>
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 60%">
                                    <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I want to place the tooltips at the end of each progress bar. As i already mentioned i thought i would combine the two placement options but it seems i can't give multiple parameters. Also what could i do so they are permanently displayed (currently they appear only on mouse hover). I managed to get them to display when the document loads but then as soon as i hover over them they disapper only to appear again on hover. What do i do so that they are permanently displayed?

Comment: Do u want all tooltips on right?

Comment: for the moment let's say yes. i just want to know how that could be done and then be concerned about what actual objects are affected :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

#### [Tooltip Extension](https://github.com/andresgutgon/bootstrap-tooltip-extension)

with a li'l modification to achieve this

**JQUERY**

```
$('.progress-bar')
  .tooltip({ placement: 'top-right', trigger: 'manual' })
  .tooltip('show');

$('.progress-bar')
  .next('.tooltip')
  .find('.tooltip-arrow')
  .addClass('toolright');

$('.carousel.slide').carousel({ interval: false });
```

**CSS**

```
.toolright {
    bottom: -5px;
    right: 12px;
    border-width: 5px 5px 0;
    border-top-color: black;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/HeVC9/1/

Comment: while i appreciate your help on displaying them permanently, this is not what i was trying to achieve. i want the tooltip to appear like in the first image

Comment: Thanks alot for your time, this is indeed useful. What i want to know, isn't there a quick and simple way to achieve this through jquery alone?

Comment: @morgred didn't find any but There may be some way to achieve this using jquery. Plugin will save your time :)